# How convert_underscores works of Header method in FAST-API?

Tags: python, fastapi

Here are codes of Header method in `param_functions.py`

```py
def Header(  # noqa: N802
    default: Any,
    *,
    alias: Optional[str] = None,
    convert_underscores: bool = True,
    title: Optional[str] = None,
    description: Optional[str] = None,
    gt: Optional[float] = None,
    ge: Optional[float] = None,
    lt: Optional[float] = None,
    le: Optional[float] = None,
    min_length: Optional[int] = None,
    max_length: Optional[int] = None,
    regex: Optional[str] = None,
    deprecated: Optional[bool] = None,
    **extra: Any,
) -> Any:
    return params.Header(
        default,
        alias=alias,
        convert_underscores=convert_underscores,
        title=title,
        description=description,
        gt=gt,
        ge=ge,
        lt=lt,
        le=le,
        min_length=min_length,
        max_length=max_length,
        regex=regex,
        deprecated=deprecated,
        **extra,
    )
```

And here are codes of Header class in `params.py`

```py
class Header(Param):
    in_ = ParamTypes.header

    def __init__(
        self,
        default: Any,
        *,
        alias: Optional[str] = None,
        convert_underscores: bool = True,
        title: Optional[str] = None,
        description: Optional[str] = None,
        gt: Optional[float] = None,
        ge: Optional[float] = None,
        lt: Optional[float] = None,
        le: Optional[float] = None,
        min_length: Optional[int] = None,
        max_length: Optional[int] = None,
        regex: Optional[str] = None,
        deprecated: Optional[bool] = None,
        **extra: Any,
    ):
        self.convert_underscores = convert_underscores
        super().__init__(
            default,
            alias=alias,
            title=title,
            description=description,
            gt=gt,
            ge=ge,
            lt=lt,
            le=le,
            min_length=min_length,
            max_length=max_length,
            regex=regex,
            deprecated=deprecated,
            **extra,
        )
```

I tried Header method of FAST-API.
Now I'm curious about it.

If I set convert_underscores=False in Header method, FAST-API does not convert hyphen to underscore. So I think convert_underscores is just flag for converting.

How does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic to replace the underscores with hyphens is done in [get_param_field](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.63.0/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L390-L391) function:

```
if not field_info.alias and getattr(field_info, "convert_underscores", None):
    alias = param.name.replace("_", "-")
```